# Status of Approach of constructing Hamiltonians from Transfer Matrix

Tags: hamiltonian, ising-model, spin-models, lattice-gauge-theory

I am studying this old paper from J.B.Kogut on lattice gauge theories and spin systems [Rev. Mod. Phys. 51, 659(1979)].
This paper discusses about the way of constructing a quantum Hamiltonian using the transfer matrix approach. For example, from the classical Ising model, he discusses about construction of Transverse field Hamiltonian using the above approach.

I am not sure If I understand it well enough. But the approach relies on to be able to interpret Transfer Matrix as an operator on some Hilbert space and to be able to write it as,
$$T =  e^{-\tau H}$$
in some scaling limit. Where H is the related Hamiltonian.

I am wondering what are the advantages of this approach in long run because I don't see anyone discussing this construction for some other lattice spin models such as clock model. In particular, I want to know what happened to this? Is there some research going on which developed from these ideas. Who are the people working on such things?

Comment: The same construction for the clock and Potts models has been discussed in the literature in the 80s. Do you need references?

Comment: Yes Please, I did not know. Also, is there some research area related to these things? I recently completed my master's and am exploring what to follow up for in PhD.

Comment: You can start for example with these old papers about the Potts model: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0375960172909279 , https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.24.218 and then go to the papers citing them.